# ViewHolder with information from multiple database tables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-viewholder

I am trying to have my `RecyclerView` / `ViewHolder` / `ListAdapter` hold information from two different tables, but cannot figure out how to do so.

My two tables

`BudgetCategory`

- Title (Primary Key)
- Budget

`Transaction`

- ID (PK)
- Category Title (Foreign Key)
- Amount Spent

Based on the Android Kotlin Fundamentals course, I currently have a `RecyclerView` / `ViewHolder` / `ListAdapter` that displays a list of `BudgetCategory` items. This works great. However, I believe the view would be more useful if I could also display the current amount spent in the same `ViewHolder` (like the picture below). My problem is, I don't know how to properly perform a query of the `Transaction` table to get the amount spent in a `BudgetCategory` and update the `ViewHolder` without performing that query on the main UI thread. Especially because, the query of the `Transaction` table is entirely based on what `BudgetCategory` object the `ViewHolder` currently has.

[image: ViewHolder of Budget Cateogry]

That is the summary of the problem. Here is everything I have tried so far.

Inside my `ViewHolder` I tried to make a call like:

```
binding.spent = transactionDao.getSpentInCategory(category.title, startDate, endDate).value
```

Of course, the problem with this is the query returns `LiveData<Double>` which is an asynchronous call, so when I call `.value` on it, there is nothing there yet, so the "$Spent" in the image above is always blank. I also couldn't figure out how to observe that so the view would know to update itself when there was actually something in the `LiveData`.

I then tried to create a new data class `BudgetCategoryOverview` which had a `BudgetCategory` and a `Double` for the amount spent. I then changed my `ListAdapter` and `ViewHolder` to use `BudgetCategoryOverview` instead of `BudgetCategory`. To populate `BudgetCategoryOverview` I tried two different things:

1. In my `Fragment` in `observe` method of my `LiveData<BudgetCategory>` I tried to populate the list of `BudgetCategoryOverview`. This failed with an exception that I cannot make DB queries on the main UI thread.
2. In the `ViewModel` I tried to use suspending functions to populate a list (code shown below), but this failed because in the `populateBudgetCategoryOverviewList()` `categories.value` was always null.

```
lateinit var categories = LiveData<List<BudgetCategory>>
var budgetCategories = MutableLiveData<MutableList<BudgetCategoryOverview>>()

init{
    budgetCategories.value = mutableListOf()
    getBudgetCategoriesAndSpent()
}

private fun getBudgetCategoriesAndSpent(){
    uiScope.launch{
        updateBudgetCategories()
        populateBudgetCategoryOverviewList()
    }
}

private suspend fun updateBudgetCategories(){
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        categories = budgetCategoryDao.getAllBudgetCategories()
    }
}

private suspend fun populateBudgetCategoryOverviewList(){
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        budgetCategories.value?.clear()
        for( category in categories.value!! ){
            val spent = transactionDao.getSpentInCategory(category.title, startDate, endDate)
            budgetCategories.value!!.add(BudgetCategoryOverview(category, spent))
        }
    }
}
```

The last thing I tried was to create a `@DatabaseView` class, but the problem with this is the amount spent is based on a `startDate` and an `endDate` so I cannot create a database view based on a query statement that isn't a compile time constant.

I feel like I am searching for the wrong things online which is why I am here. What am I doing wrong? I am sure this isn't that uncommon of a use case. What is the standard approach to solve this?

Let me know if you need to see anymore code, but since I tried so many different things, I wasn't sure what versions of what code to post.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a short version of what is your question? all this description and there is no exact problem.

Comment: I am trying to put information from two different database tables into the same `RecyclerView`. I have a list of categories from the first table. Based on which category is populating the current view item, I need the DB results from the second table to also be displayed in that same view item. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I think the proper term is I am trying to put info from two different DB tables into the same `ViewHolder` not the same `RecyclerView`. I also updated the question to be more clear upfront and then provide examples of what I have tried

Comment: If data is related `JOIN` your tables together and then query the records then display them on your list. if the data between two tables are unrelated and both need a different layout you can use RecyclerView's `viewtype`

Comment: OK, so I have "solved" this by observing the `BudgetCategory` list and then when that list changes updating my list of `BudgetCategoryOverview`, but your `JOIN` solution might make more sense. When I attempted to use a `@DatabaseView` I tried to get the exact query - including the date range. But I think if I take your suggestion, create a `@DatabaseView` that just joins the tables, then query the records from that view, this will give me what I want and be a better solution than my double observing.

Comment: @abstractArrow Thank you. I got wrapped around the axle on this one and was trying all the wrong things. Creating a standard `@Query` with a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables is exactly what I needed! I didn't know that you could create a new Object in Kotlin from an Android Room DB Query, but this is what I ended up doing. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help you.